# Dynamic text on TCPDF-Laravel footer

Tags: php, laravel, static, laravel-8, tcpdf

First of all I'm 90% sure this is me not knowing some basic stuff about how php static methods work, so please forgive my ignorance. I also could not find any info on this on SO, so hopefully this won't be a duplicate.

I'm working on a project with laravel and using the TCPDF-Laravel extension, and I have a footer that needs to say different things based on a condidition:

```
   if ($someCondition) {
         $footerText = <<<EOD
                text if true
          EOD;
    } else {
         $footerText = <<<EOD
                text if false
          EOD;
     }

    PDF::setFooterCallback(function($pdf,$footerText){
        $pdf->SetY(-15);
        $pdf->Write(0, $footerText, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
    });
```

But for some reason, again probably my ignorance, this doesn't run. It says 'too few arguments given', as if $footerText wasn't defined or was null.

I have already tried declaring the variable before the if bracket, declaring the function outside the setFooterCallBack, and using $this->footerText but it didn't work.

Comment: Nothing to do with static methods, more with lambda or [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Just add `use` at the end of your anonymous function (callback) like `function($pdf) use($footerText) {` (to inherit the varialbe `$footerText`). The `setFooterCallback` calls the function you give as an argument and decides the given arguments for that function, in your example the first one is `$pdf`, so there should be some object given by `setFooterCallback`. The second argument `$footerText` is just your ignorance of not knowing how stuff works ;)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it, and sorry, guess I have to take a deeper look into php anonymous functions.

Comment: Yea I'll post an answer on that particular subject ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to make this simple.

`PDF::setFooterCallback()` requires a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as a first argument. That's where you pass in `function($pdf) {}`. In order to expand the functions scope for a variable like `$footerText`, you have to use `use` to inherit it like so: `function($pdf) use($footerText)`.

The reason why you get this error is because you set `$footerText` as a second argument after `$pdf`, which `setFooterCallback` does not know of and therefor, it's not set and calls a `too few arguments` exception which is normal.

```
// outputs "Howdy'ho!"
(function($what) {
    echo $what;
})("Howdy'ho!");


// will throw an exception `too few arguments`
(function($what) {
    echo $what;
})();

// will output null, because it can be called without an argument.
(function($what = null) {
    echo $what;
})();
```

So theoretically, setting `$footerText` to a default `null` would work, but this is of course not what you intended to do.

```
PDF::setFooterCallback(function($pdf, $footerText = null){
  $pdf->SetY(-15);
  $pdf->Write(0, $footerText, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
});
```

Just inherit the variable `$footerText` using `use`.

```
PDF::setFooterCallback(function($pdf) use(footerText) {
  $pdf->SetY(-15);
  $pdf->Write(0, $footerText, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
});
```